# Vue-Router - passing data from one route component to another

Tags: vue.js

I need help. I have array of objects in one component (projects.vue) "/projects". I want to pass that values to another component(details.vue) "/details". In those objects, I have "id" property and "name" property. So - the goal is to make template in details.vue, which can display "name" properties of those objects, for example - `<h1>{{projects[1].name}}</h1>`.
Id must be used as key value.

In details.vue, I have following method:

```
created() {
   
    this.$http.get('/projects/' + this.id)
    .then(function(data){
       // console.log(data)
        this.project = data.body;
        console.log(data.body)
    })
}
```

I'm new with vue-router and confused.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options, you could use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to persist the data for the lifetime of your application (and share it between components).

You could also send the data as route parameters, or use a different service to store the data.

However I generally advise to do such tasks with vuex.